# Is there a way to pass an element name concatenated with a variable in PHP isset function? e.g isset($_GET['submit'.'$x'])

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, get, isset

I recently came across a scenario in which I have to create a survey form through PHP. 
As an initial step:

- I have saved two survey questions in a table named 'questions' and
  the database name is also 'questions'.
- I used a for loop to Pull every question saved in database with a two
  radio button saying 'Yes/No' beneath each question. Radio buttons are also appearing due to for loop.

such as:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE 1";   //return all rows query
$row = mysqli_query($conn,$query);     //run query
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($row); //save the num of rows 
// echo $num_rows

for($x=1; $x<=$num_rows; $x++) {
    $get_question="SELECT `questions` FROM `questions` WHERE id='$x'";
    $question = mysqli_query($conn,$get_question);
    ?>    
    <?php
    while($var = mysqli_fetch_assoc($question)) {
        echo "Q:"." ". $var['questions']."</br>";
    }
    ?>

    <form name="survey" action="" method="GET">
        <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="question<?php echo $x?>">Yes</br>
        <input type="radio" value="No" name="question<?php echo $x?>">No</br>
        <?php
        echo "</br>";
}
?>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</center>
```

Now, In order to differentiate each question's 'yes/No' option from other question's 'Yes/No' option, I have concatenated the variable 'x'(the one used to start the loop in forloop) with the name of the radio button.

So that for Question1 the radio buttons will have the name "question1", for Question 2 the name will be "question2" and so on.

The complexity occurs when I want to fetch the value of radio button through 'isset' function. As the name is varying so how can I pass a variable in isset function.

like it must be :

```
if( isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $get_value= **isset($_GET['question$x']**)
}
```

I have also tried like:

```
$get_value= **isset($_GET['question'.'$x']**)
```

and other similar methods, but none of these works. 
I will highly appreciate your help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `isset($_GET['question'.'$x'])` for one thing is not correct syntax since it will always be considered as being set. You want another conditional or a ternary operator.

Comment: Why are you selecting all rows from the same table two times?

Comment: use and array in your form, like `question[$x]`. Better would be to use the index (ID) of the question, so you know which question is used. Just in case you start making selections of questions.

Comment: You first code block doesn't really relate to the question. But it shows that you probably don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your SELECT query with this : `SELECT questions FROM questions WHERE id='".$x."'`

Comment: and why were the ticks removed?

Comment: definantly "WHERE id='$x'"  is valid and "." is use for string concatenation

Answer (score -1):

Yes it should be possible: `isset($_GET['question' . $x])`

Variables in strings with a single quote won't work. You don't have to put it in a string to concatenate it.

These would both work:

- `'question' . $x`
- `"question$x"`

Comment: I tried them already but they didn't work. It seems like the isset function don't accept variables. 
Is there anyother way ?

Comment: I tried to make a small code snippet which does exactly the same. It does seem to work for me: 
`$data = ['question1' => 'hi']; $i = 1; $get_var = isset($data['question' . $i]); var_dump($get_var);`